# How to update recyclerView when button is clicked in an alertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-recyclerview

// RecyclerAdapter (On click listener for the image)

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
          Integer p = getAdapterPosition()
                Drawable d = imageView.getDrawable();
                ((MainActivity) itemView.getContext()).showOrganisation(p,d);
            }
});
```

// Main Activity

```
 public void showOrganisation(Integer p, Drawable d) {

    myDialogOrg.setContentView(R.layout.popup_organisation);
    TextView selectButton = myDialogOrg.findViewById(R.id.popOrgClose);
    ImageView imageView = myDialogOrg.findViewById(R.id.popUpLogo);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(d);

    myDialogOrg.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

    selectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences pref = v.getContext().getSharedPreferences("CheckBoxStateOrganisationer", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

           // Send mysql query to database that a charity is selected
           // Code
                            response{
           // Store State of checkbox
               editor.putBoolean("CheckBoxOrganisationer"+p, true);
               editor.commit();
             }
            ////////////////////////////////
            // update state of checkbox in//
            //////////////////////////////// 

          -> I've added code here <-  

            // Dismiss popup window
            myDialogOrg.dismiss();
        }
    });
    myDialogOrg.show();
}
```

What I've tried is Fragment.adapter.notifyItemChanged(p); 
and Fragment.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

The outcome is that the cardView in the recyclerview gets cleared and the original layout of the recycled cardView is displayed.

Is there a way to reload the "MyViewHolder" of the recycler.adapter for one position so that the cardview updates?

// Organisation_Fragment

```
       Initiates the adapter
```

When the button in the AlertDialog is clicked and the alert is dismissed the checkbox of a specific item(position) in the recyclerView should appear selected.

[image: AlertDialog displayed over recyclerView]

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I usually add a method in my Adapter which reacts to the data change

Adapter:

```
    public void updateData(List<String> newList){
        suggestions.clear();
        if(newList!=null) suggestions.addAll(newList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Your Activity:

```
private AutoCompleteAdapter adapter;

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
adapter = new AutoCompleteAdapter
                            (context, suggestions, etAnswer);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

your click listener

```
selectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         // your other code
            ////////////////////////////////
            // update state of checkbox in//
            //////////////////////////////// 

          -> I've added code here <-  
           adapter.updateData(yourNewList);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did however end up just reloading the fragment into the fragment container and commit the same fragment, which was already visible, once more to get it updated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the adapter method

```
adapter.notifyItemChanged(position, your Object);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This line did sadly not work in my case and just cleared the integers displayed in the cardView at that given position.